# jQuery form check - Add new keywords based on Select menu value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a simple form with few select and few input fields. I want to perform jQuery check for only these three fields inside the form:

```
<form action="action/buy.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="boosterForm">
<select name="Quantity" id="selectQuantity" tabindex="1" class="span2">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        ..................
        <option value="99">99</option>
</select>

<input class="span11" id="wizard_url" type="text" name="Website" placeholder="http://www.example.com">

<input class="span11" type="text" name="Keywords">

<button class="btn btn-large btn-warning" type="submit" name="campaignSubmit" value="Buy Now" >Buy Now</button>

</form>
```

What I want to do is allow/block user when he selects from select menu "Quantity" following values 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45....99 to enter 1 new keyword separated by coma for every three Quantity.

For example if he picks #3 from "Quantity" drop down menu he is not allowed to add any commas (,) inside "Keywords" field, if he choose between #4-#6 he is allowed to enter only one commas, if he choose #7-#9 he is allowed to enter only two commas, and all the way to #99 when he is allowed to enter 32 commas.

If they enter more commas then allowed I want to display a simple warning below the field letting them know they can't add more keywords, e.g. "Maximum number of keywords added". Also I don't want to let them submit the form until they fulfill this.

And last thing, they also can't submit the form if the field "Website" is empty.

I was trying some pre-made jQuery form check scripts but none of them offer what I need above and I am no expert in jQuery to make it by myself.

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if someone selects `4` or `5` or `10`, what is the logic and why commas, isn't it should be keywords ?

Comment: if someone selects 4 or 5 it will allow them to add 2 commas since its between 3-6 and if user enters 10 user will be allowed to enter 3 keywords since its between 9-12. The reason why commas is because keywords are usually separated by commas. I added small changes in text so you can easier understand. Thanks

Comment: Check the answer, it works (4-6 = 1 comma, 7-9 = 2 commas, 10-12 = 3 commas and so on) and website can't be left empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (It works as `4-6` = `1` comma is allowed, `7-9` = `2` commas are allowed, `10-12` = `3` commas are allowed and so on and `website` can't be left empty)

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectQuantity').on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val > 3) {
            var div = val / 3, mod = val % 3;
            if(mod == 0) {
                var commas = div-1;
            }
            else {
                var commas = parseInt(div);
            }
            $('input[name="Keywords"]').attr('data-commas', commas);
        }
    });

    $('[name="campaignSubmit"]').closest('form').on('submit', function(e){
        var el = $('input[name="Keywords"]');
        val = el.val(), commas = (val.split(',').length -1), msg = '';
        if(commas) {
            if(!el.attr('data-commas')) { 
                msg = "You can't put any commas in 'Keywords' field !";
            }
            else {
                if( el.attr('data-commas') && commas > el.attr('data-commas')) {
                    msg = "You can't put more than " + el.attr('data-commas') + " comma(s) in 'Keywords' field!";
                }
            }
        }
        if($('input[name="Website"]').val() == '') {
            msg += "\nWebsite can't be left blank !";
        }
        if(msg) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/8gxaV/2/)

Comment: Another great answer from you. Works as needed. Thanks a lot!